# How to check if a PyObject is a String or Unicode for a Python C Extension

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

In Python(2), the idiomatic way to check if a variable is of `str` or `unicode` type is

```
isinstance(var, basestr)
```

In the [Concrete Object Layer documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/concrete.html), I did not see anything resembling `basestr`.

Currently I am validating variables like the following:

```
PyObject *key;
//...
if (!PyString_Check(key) && !PyUnicode_Check(key)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Key must be string");
    return NULL;
}
```

Is there a more concise way to check if a `PyObject` is of type `str` or `unicode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `PyBaseString_Type` (see for example [`stringobject.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/stringobject.h#L55), strangely I also couldn't find it in the documentation...) which is identical to `basestring`:

```c
PyObject *key;
// ...
if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(key, &PyBaseString_Type)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "key must be a string.");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - and just to confirm, there is no function `PyBaseString_Check` that would obviate the need to pass in `&PyBaseString_Type` ?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen unfortunatly there is no `PyBaseString_Check`.